# Xml problem in Blackberry application

Tags: xml, blackberry, java-me

Tell me anyone what is the steps follow to use Xml in our blackberry Application ,Actually i have created xml in own local host but there is nothing to write .tell me how i write the that xml and how  i  read this xml.

Comment: Google is your friend,  show the code you've written or the answers you've found but don't understand, and then maybe there will be something to tell...

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! For starters, choose a unique username. Then, when asking a question, be specific about what you are trying to do. What have you tried? Why doesn't that work? you'll get much better results than a generic question. Finally, spelling and grammar count! People need to be able to easily read your question.

Answer (score 0):

Writing to XML on blackberry platforms is almost equivalent to writing to XML in normal java programs. You can open a FileOutputStream and write to a file with the .xml extension.

But the better alternative for large XML files is to use java's DOM/SAX parsers and use the blackberry XMLWriter class to write the DOM object to a XML file.

For reading and writing to a specific file from the res directory, you can get a resource stream and the java DOM/SAX parsers should be able to parse the file from the stream for you.